# Swift 3 Initializing buttons

Tags: uibutton, swift3

Where does one put button initialization code for controls.  It won't work in ViewController.swift correct? because I need it to init immediately, not after a button is pressed.

For example I want rounded corners on the buttons.

```
@IBAction func buttonAdd(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let button = buttonAdd!

    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan

    // button.backgroundColor = .clear
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    button.layer.borderWidth = 1
    button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
}
```

However the this let statement won't work outside of the function either.
Do I need to put init code in a function?
Where would I call the function from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'buttonAdd' is a function, not a button.

try this code.

```
    if let button = sender as? UIButton
    {
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan

        // button.backgroundColor = .clear
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        button.layer.borderWidth = 1
        button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    }
```

---

So, you want to init the button with roundedCorner and border.

There's a 'viewDidLoad' function that called only once in view controller's life cycle.
If you want to do something only once, do it in 'viewDidLoad' function.

```
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let btn = UIButton(type: .custom)
        btn.frame = .init(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 30)
        btn.setTitle("Hello", for: .normal)
        btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
        btn.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        btn.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        btn.layer.borderWidth = 1

        // you must call this for rounded corner
        btn.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.view.addSubview(btn)
    }
```

If you created your button in Interface Builder, You can do it like this.

```
@IBOutlet weak var btn: UIButton!
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    btn.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    btn.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    btn.layer.borderWidth = 1

    // you must call this for rounded corner
    btn.layer.masksToBounds = true
}
```

Comment: I realize buttonAdd is a function, but its an button Action function so it wont get hit until a button is pressed, so where do i put init code for the button. It obviously has to reside outside of that function. Again do i have to put init code in a call or function?? And other thing not clear to me is where  is property .Name or its equivelent in Swift. Without a name property how can you reference a control globally?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question...You would put button init code in ViewController.Swift...in the following function created automatically by the View Controller and you must add button Outlet in addition to button Action.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let button = buttonAdd!

    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan

  //  button.backgroundColor = .clear
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    button.layer.borderWidth = 1
    button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
```